# Postback from Jquery load()-ed content

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

First some background:

I have main Aspx page (using Master Page), that contains several Web User Controls. Most of those controls, are in their separate Update Panels.

One of those controls can take up to several seconds before it is loaded, which considerably slows the overall loading time. Hence I decided to load this control with Jquery's load() method.

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#divContent").load("newPageWithControlInside.aspx #container", 
           function () {
              $("#imgSpinner").hide();
              $("#divContent").show();
           });
       }; 
</script>


 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDetails" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <div id="divWrapper">
         <img id="imgSpinner" src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
         <div id="divContent" style="display: none"></div>
       </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Since I could not figure out how to directly load() Web User Control, I inserted it into a new aspx page (with the same master as Main).

This part works like a charm .. Rest of the page is loaded first, after which 
jquery load() is called and the content of the page/control is successfully loaded.

And now comes the problem:

The User Control contains Update Panel with several buttons. Those buttons fire postbacks, that load additional data. This part so far is also working, the postback goes through, data is loaded and update panel is updated (at least in code-behind during debug).

But when I look at the page, the whole content of page/control that was loaded with Jquery suddenly vanishes. The imgSpinner is shown with divContent hidden in it's basic (first-time request) state, before the jquery load() event is fired.

And the additional data that was loaded during the postback just vanish, because there exist no corresponding controls that could be filled.

Am I making some mistake ? Or is this the result of combining client-side content loading with server-side postback event handling ? And if it's the second, how can I achieve the desired result ?

Update:
Mentioned question:  [After Post Back my jQuery code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184643)
is not a duplicate of my problem. I do not have a problem with Jquery after Postback. My problem deals with the loss of Update Panel state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After Post Back my jQuery code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184643/after-post-back-my-jquery-code-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Found out, I would need to use a (hidden) button that would serve as the postback caller for my dynamically created buttons.

Since this was not how I wanted to resolve this I switched to using IFrames as an easier solution.