# Bootstrap Datepicker settings reset after page event using ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-datepicker

Here's the deal: bootstrap datepicker works like a charm when the page loads by the first time. But when I execute any event (button click, show modal, hide modal, change paging in GridView, etc) datepicker stops working. How can I maintain the datepicker settings no matter what occurs in the page?

Here's the part of the code that matters:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right:30px">
        <label>Data início:</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='dataInicioPicker' style="width:0;">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbDataInicio" CssClass="form-control text-datas"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <label>Data fim:</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='dataFimPicker' style="width:0">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbDataFim" CssClass="form-control text-datas"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dataInicioPicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            language: "pt-BR",
        });

        $('#dataFimPicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            language: "pt-BR",
        });
    });
</script>
```

**IMPORTANT:**

- I'm using bootstrap datepicker version 1.6.4
- I CAN'T use another version - company's orders
- I CAN'T modify bootstrap datepicker code - company's orders
- I CAN'T use another datepicker component - company's orders
- There's no javascript error occurring (actually, there's no other javascript at all)
- If I put a `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` to redefine the settings in the textboxes in every ASP.NET event method, the datepicker continues to work as it should (but I don't want to do this to every-freakin-method every-freakin-time)

Comment: Change the Company :D As it says Webforms, first question do you use update panels. If so check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184643/after-post-back-my-jquery-code-not-working

Comment: @SehaxX NAILED IT! I wasn't using update panels, but this code did the deed. Thank you! (and I'll consider changing the company after that, haha!). If you want to put it as an answer, I can give you the marking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per this link:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //jquery code
    });
    var parameter = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    parameter.add_endRequest(function() {
        //jquery code again for working after postback
    });
</script>
```

Cheers,

Comment: @thiagoprzy ok, I have edited the answer. Glad it helped you.